# Why nm libc.so reports no symbols?

Tags: gcc, libc, nm

I've built a simple program like this:

g++ application.cpp -o application.exe

and then executed the command;

```
ldd application.exe
...
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
...
```

I want to list all the symbols of the libc library:

```
nm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
nm: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: no symbols

nm --defined-only /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
nm: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: no symbols
```

Why nm reports no symbols? If libc.so.6 is not a library, but a some kind of a link to the actual library, then how can I find the actual library?

Comment: Is `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` stripped? What is the output of `file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`?

Comment: You can try `readelf -s libc.so.6`, also see [Why nm shows no symbols for /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282616/why-nm-shows-no-symbols-for-lib-i386-linux-gnu-libc-so-6) .

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By default, `nm` reads the `.symtab` section in ELF objects, which is optional in non-relocatable objects.  With the [`-D`/`--dynamic` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html#index-dynamic-symbols), you can instruct `nm` to read the dynamic symbol table (which are the symbols actually used at run time).  You may also want to use `--with-symbol-versions` because glibc uses symbol versioning extensively.

Alternatively, you can use `eu-readelf --symbols=.dynsym` or `objdump -Tw`.  (`readelf -sDW` does not include symbol versioning information.)

Comment: Thanks! Why --dynamic isn't a default option then??

Comment: The `nm` command is very old and dynamic linking did not exist back then (and some binutils targets still do not support it). Changing the data source based on object type would likely be too confusing.

Comment: OK, maybe there exist more modern and convenient tools for analysing library symbols then?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer: Curiously, the commentary I remember from 1998 already regarded it as a bug that `nm` doesn't list exported symbols from stripped `.so` files by default.

Comment: `--with-symbol-versions` appears to be the default with `nm`, so only the `-D/--dynamic` is required for to read the dynamic symbol table.